# How do you make a layered solution's UI project resolve EF Entities without referencing the data access layer

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture, layered

I am working on a WinForms application which I have structured with 3 layers, each layer a separate project, as follows:

[image: Projects in solution]

Within the SampleNtierDAL project is a DalServices class which is defined as follows:

```
namespace SampleNtierDAL
{
    public class DalServices
    {
        public static List<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            List<Employee> employeeList = null;
            using (SampleNtierEntities aSampleNtierEntitiesDbContext = new SampleNtierEntities())
            {
                employeeList = (from emp in aSampleNtierEntitiesDbContext.Employees select emp).ToList();
            }
            return employeeList;
        }
    }
}
```

Within the SampleNtierBLL project is a BllServices class defined as follows:

```
namespace SampleNtierBLL
{
    public class BllSerices
    {
        public static List<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            return DalServices.GetEmployees();
        }
    }
}
```

Te SampleNtierUI project has a WinForm button event which is supposed to ask the BllServices to get an employee list as follows:

```
namespace SampleNtierUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnGetListOfEmployees_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Employee> anEmployeeList = BllSerices.GetEmployees();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the WinForm is not able to see the entity model called "Employee" which was created by Entity Frameworks 6. The SampleNtierBLL project class BllServices sees the class because it references the SampleNtierDAL and has a use statement at the top to resolve the Employee class.  I thought about adding similar references in the WinForm to resolve the Employee class but I have seen in other articles that you are not supposed to make references to the Data Access Layer but such articles don't show how to address this problem I have.
Can someone please show me how to get the Entity model (Employee class) recognized by the UI (WinForm) without making references to the data access layer where the Entity Framework generated the Entity called Employee?
Thanks in advance.

**Update to my post 11/5/2015 5:13 PM**

After more testing with the procedure I added in on post 11/5/2015 3:14 PM I found that it does actually also work on Visual Studio 2015 with .NET 4.5.2.

**Update to my post 11/5/2015 3:14 pm:**

Thank you Reza for all the work you put into providing the response information. I was not able to make your solution work with Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2015 as it is documented. However, I did find an internet video on Pluralsight.com by Julie Lerman which does provide a solution. Her solution did not mention to use the NuGet manage part which your's did so I added that to the mix and ended up with a working project.  Julie Lerman's video is titled:

"Separating Generated Domain Classes from EDMX" and is located here:

http://www.pluralsight.com/training/player?course=entity-framework5-getting-started&author=julie-lerman&name=ef5-m6-solutions&clip=2&mode=live

By combining part of your procedure with hers I ended with the following steps which work for me on Visual Studio 2013 but not on Visual Studio 2015.

My sample originally had the following project:

- SampleNtierDAL
- SampleNtierBLL
- SampleNtierUI

To this list of projects I add a fourth project called SampleNtierModels so the list is now as follows:

- SampleNtierDAL
- SampleNtierBLL
- SampleNtierUI
- SampleNtierModels

**Steps to follow:**
1) Setup project references as follow:

1. SampleNtierBLL references SampleNtierDAL and SampleNtierModels
2. SampleNtierDAL references SampleNtierModels
3. SampleNtierDAL does not reference any project
4. SampleNtierUI references SampleNtierBLL and SampleNtierModels

2) Next, start the File Explorer program (the tool used to browse file system files) and move the ModelEmployee.tt file from the DAL project file folder to the models file folder.

3) Using the Visual Studio Solution Explorer, go to the SampleNtierModels project, right click and select Add Existing Item. In the dialog, select "All Files" in order to see the ModelEmployee.tt file and select it to add it to the project (do not choose link file).

4) Next, select the SampleNtierDAL project, then right click on the ModelEmployee.tt file and delete it which also automatically delete all the .cs files under it. When done the ModelEmployee.tt node should be gone.

5) Select the SampleNtierModels project then click on the ModelEmployee.tt node which will open up the MoadelEmployee.tt file in the editor.  At the top of the contents is an assigment to a const string inputFile.  Set this string to locate the ModelEmployee.edmx file as follows:

```
const string inputFile = @"..\SampleNiter\SampleNtierDAL\ModelEmployee.edmx
```

5) Next, select the SampleNtierDAL project and open the ModelEmployee.Context.tt file and scroll down ot the section referencing using clauses and add the SampleNtierModels name space as shown below:

```
if (container.FunctionImports.Any())
{
#>
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Linq;
using SampleNtierModels;
<#
}
```

7) Select the SampleNtierBLL project, open the BLLServices.cs file and add the following using statements:

```
using SampleNtierModels;
using SampleNtierDAL;
```

8) Select the SampleNtierDAL project, open the DalServices.cs file and add the following using statement:

```
using SampleNtierModels;
```

7) Select the SampleNtierUI project, open the Form1.cs file and add the following using statements:

```
using SampleNtierModels;
using SampleNtierBLL
```

8) Click on Tools in menu bar then NuGet Package Manager then

1. Select installed packages
2. Search for Entity Framework
3. Select the displayed EntityFramework package then click its
   "Manage" button
4. In the list box make sure the following are selected:
   SampleNtierBLL, SampleNtierDAL, SamleNtierUI

9) Select the SampleNtierDAL project, right click on ModelEmployee.Context.tt node and select "Run Custom Tool".

10) Select the SampleNtierModels project, right click on ModelEmployee.tt node and select "Run Custom Tool".

11) Copy the entire contents of the App.Config file in the SampleNtierDAL project into the App.Config file of the SampleNtierUI project.

Below is a sample picture showing the what the project looked like in the end along with a sample debug session showing 3 rows of data returned from entity framework which originated from the DAL then to the BLL and finally the UI.  The Winform UI also shows no reference was needed to the DAL.

This problem is now solved so once again thank you Reza for helping to solve this problem. I have left a message with Juile requesting for an update to here process which includes Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

Comment: Employee is defined in your EF Model and without reference to that you will not have access to it. You could create a ViewModel that encapsulates what you need in Employee and return that to your view instead if you don't want to reference the EF library

Comment: Your data model should be defined in a separate, common assembly, which both the DAL and the UI can reference. Your data model should not take a dependency on the ORM.

Comment: The entity "Employee" was created using the VS 2015 template called "Ado.net Entity Data Model" which generated the Employee class as part of the "Data Base First" EF approach.  I guess I could try moving the contents of "ModelEmployee.tt" out of the SampleNtierDAL project and into a separate project. I'm not sure if the other components of EF in the SampleNtierDAL project such as the .edmx diagram will still work.  A quick and simple solution would be to just make another project and duplicate the entities there. I'll try moving them out and let you know what happens.

Comment: @Robertcode It works in other project. But in a specific way. You should add existing item and choose your `ModelEmployee.tt` as `Add as Link` to other project.

Comment: @Robertcode I posted a complete step by step answer that may be useful for future readers. Hope you find it helpful:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short Answer

You should put your models in a separate project than your `DAL` to make your models visible to `User Interface (UI)` project without referencing `Data Access Layer (DAL)` Project. And all your projects should have a reference to your models project.

The key point in doing this using a `Database/Model First` Approach is "Add Existing Item" to your models project and select `.tt` file of models and choose `Add as Link` from dropdown of Add button in the dialog.

### Step by Step Guide to Create a Layered Solution

To put your models in a separate project using entity framework follow these stpes:

**Create Projects**

1. Create a project and name it for example `Sample.DAL`
2. Create another project and name it `Sample.Models`
3. Create another project and name it `Sample.BLL`
4. Create another project and name it `Sample.UI`

**Config References**

Add references to projects with these rules:

1. `Sample.UI` is dependent to `Sample.BLL` and `Sample.Models`
2. `Sample.BLL` is dependent to `Sample.DAL` and `Sample.Models`
3. `Sample.DAL` is dependent to `Sample.Models`
4. `Sample.Models` has no dependency to other projects

**Config Sample.DAL**

1. Add your `SampleDB.edmx` to `Sample.DAL` project
2. Expand `Sample.edmx` node and expand `SampleDB.tt` node and delete all .cs files under `SampleDB.tt`
3. In properties of `SampleDB.tt` clear `CustomTool`

**Config Sample.Models**

1. `Add Existing Item` to `Sample.Models` and in the dialog, go to folder of `Sample.DAL` and choose `All files` from combo box and select `SampleDB.tt` and click on drop down of Add button and from the menu choose `Add As Link`
2. Choose `SampleDB.tt` and in properties, set `CustomToolNamespace` to `Sample.DAL`
3. Right click on `SampleDB.tt` and `Run Custom Tool`

**Manage Nuget Packages**

1. Right click on solution and select `Manage Nuget Packages for Solution` and select installed packages, select `Entity Framework` and click Manage. Choose `Sample.DAL` and `Sample.BLL` and `Sample.UI`

**Config Sample.BusinessLogic**

Create a `YourEntityBusinessLogic` class with this code:

```
public class YourEntityBusinessLogic
{
    public List<YourEntity> GetAll()
    {
        var context = new YourDBContext();
        return context.YourEntities.ToList();
    }
}
```

Pay attention to not expose YourDBContext in public properties or as input parameters of methods and constructors or as return values.

**Config Sample.UI**

1. Copy your connection string from `app.config` file of `Sample.DAL` and paste to `app.config` of `Sample.UI` before `<entityframework>` tag.
2. Create a `Form` and set it as start up and run this code as test in `FormLoad` or wherever you want:

```
//Shows count of records in your table
var business = new YourEntityBusinessLogic();
MessageBox.Show(business.GetAll().Count().ToString());
```

**Solution structure**

Here is the solution structure, and as you see the context is in `Sample.DAL` and models are in `Sample.Models`.

So you don't need to add a reference to `DAL` in your `UI` project.

[image]

Comment: If I invoke the service to only give me a count as you did then it does work. But I still have the same problem when I reference the entity name. Were you able to make it work with something like this:

List<Category> aListOfCategories = business.GetAll();

I presume from your example that Category is a Class with properties to form a model. My UI still does not know about the model entity such as in this case Category. Maybe because the namespace in the Entity still points to the DAL

Comment: I test the solution here and it works properly. I  test `new ProductBusiness().GetAll().ForEach(x => { MessageBox.Show(x.Name); });` and it works properly What's the problem exactly?

Comment: I am completely sure about the answer. And I made a working example and the the screenshot is from the working sample. You don't need any reference of `DAL` in `UI` if you follow steps.

Comment: Does this work in your UI project:   List<Category> aListOfCategories = business.GetAll(); or are you able to declare a Category class anywhere in your WinForm?

Comment: I tested it with product and the answer is Yes, It works properly. For example I can run `var products= business.GetAll();` and then `products.ForEach(x => { MessageBox.Show(x.Name); });`

Comment: It's because I have a reference to `Sample.Models` if you see your `GetAll` method returns a `Category` different than `Category` of `Sample.Models` it probably id because your `DAL` code generation has some problems, for example maybe your `.tt` file of your `DAL` is creating models and you have forgotten to remove `CustomToolNamespace` or you have forgotten to delete previously generated model files, ....

Comment: If you look at the image in the answer, you will see models are created in `Sample.Models` and no file is generated under `TestDB.tt` in `Sample.DAL` project. Could you follow the steps and get desired result?

Comment: Hello Reza. I have updated my post. I will click on your response to at least provide credit for your efforts.  But please note the bottom of my post contains the solution I had to use

Comment: @Robertcode I read your update, thank you for mentioning me. The difference is in step 4,5,6 that I prefer to use `Add as Link` and also change the `CustomToolNamespace` to prevent the user from changing the `tt` file. And I think probably you had some small mistake to apply the steps. But the important thing is now you made it work and I'm happy to hear that :)